# How to get count of two fields unique id in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have problem when I want to select query with 2 field and that field is unique id then I try to create table like this

```
created_at             user_id 
2013-01-05             1
2013-01-20             1
2013-01-23             2
2013-01-28             1
2013-02-01             3
2013-02-04             2
```

look that is any user_id is not unique and created_at is not unique too, so I have create query select like this code

```
SELECT MONTH( created_at ) AS month 
     , count( user_id ) AS total 
FROM applies where YEAR(created_at) = 2013 
GROUP BY month
```

this is the result

```
month             total
1                 4
2                 2
```

in the month January (1) actually I have 3 users but that is still show 4 users because count not unique `user_id` **how can I am filter that `user_id` to unique?**

Comment: Add `group by MONTH( created_at )` in the end

Comment: @shiju still not change
@_ejay that group by user_id , but group by month is not grouped. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not count duplicate `user_id` use `DISTINCT` keyword for that:

```
SELECT MONTH(created_at) AS Month
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT User_id) AS Total
FROM Table1
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

Result:

```
| MONTH | TOTAL |
-----------------
|     1 |     2 |
|     2 |     2 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa401/5)